# angularjs - ng-model input as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

**In angularjs I have this code:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="properties.foreground.value">
```

**I want it to be like:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="properties.{{type}}.value">
```

I changed a part of the model input to be a string. It does not work. Can it be done some other way?

Comment: Try `ng-model="properties[type].value">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the bracket notation to access the property and not the dot notation. This is because `ngModel` binds the attirbute to the scope using `=`, so the value is not interpolated.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="properties[type].value">
```

Comment: what if it's more dynamic than this, `a.b.c.d` or `a.f.g`

Comment: Then it would be `property[a][b][c]`

Comment: if you look at my example, I have `a` of `b.c.d` and `a` of `f.g` your answer doesn't work in this case

Comment: Open another question and I will answer. It's too difficult in comments.